# How to add new subdomain to existing kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

totally beginner with kubernetes and i believe this should be a simple question for any kubernetes expert

to put a long story short:
i have inherited a kubernetes cluster after my CTO quit his job. My goal is to make a new app accessible at a new subdomain for our company

context:

1. the app in question has a service definition and deployment definition that have been applied to the cluster (ex: kubectl apply -f new-service.yaml)
2. the pod is running the app as far as i can tell (shows up in my kubectl get pods output as ready and running)
3. and i can ping that pod from other pods in the cluster

my problem:

i do not know how to make the ingress router "work"...
i have updated my ingress yaml configuration by adding the host and service name, and I have used the command kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml to update the ingress configuration. but the new host is unreachable. I have even gone so far as to add a new host (a subdomain of our company) with a serviceName of an already functioning service that is accessible on a different subdomain -- hoping that i would see the already working app on my new subdomain. however, this new subdomain does not direct me to the app, chrome gives me the following output:

```
server IP address could not be found.

ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

is there something i'm missing here?
shouldn't i be able to add a new host to the bottom of my ingress yaml and give it a serviceName of an already working service? and then be able to access that already running app from a different subdomain?

any help at all would be so greatly appreciated -- this is the last step for me in a long journey!
here is a snip of what i added to the ingress yaml -- this matches the other entry exactly except the hostname is www3 and not www

```
- host: www3.changed-for-privacy.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: changed-for-privacy-www
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Have you configured DNS settings with your DNS provider to point to the load balancer IP of your Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: @TobiasBergkvist i believe this should already be set up! 

let me know if i'm wrong, but since the other host names in my ingress router are working as expected, i shouldn't have to reconfigure any DNS settings, right? i'm assuming that because all of the other subdomains work as expected, adding a new subdomain via the ingress configuration should be all i need

Comment: Depends on whether the DNS have been configured for the working subdomains individually - or if it uses a wildcard rule (https://serverfault.com/questions/12124/wildcard-dns-and-subdomains). Also, do the domains have https? Is cert-manager installed in the cluster? Then you might need to also specify that you want a tls-certificate in the ingress.

Comment: Another thing, I think `pathType: Prefix` is the default if not specified, in which case `- path: /*` will cause problems. You could try to remove this star/wildcard symbol.

Comment: @TobiasBergkvist great point! 
i assume that we have a wildcard rule in place, this is because i noticed that in AWS Route53 -- when i find all the records for our domain -- i do not see all of the subdomains that I would expect... but i also don't see a wildcard rule either. some of the apps that are running inside of the cluster are on subdomains that i do not see in aws Route53.

Comment: I've also tried going out of my way to add a new CNAME record (in AWS route53) on the domain for the specific subdomain that i want to add -- and i've pointed that CNAME record to the ingress router external IP -- but no success... i thought that was strange to even attempt because none of the other services have that configuration inside of AWS route 53

Comment: @TobiasBergkvist i just tried to remove the star from the `- path: /*` and there is no change

Comment: You could use something like https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php to see if DNS is setup correctly. Try entering different subdomains, including the one your are trying to use. They should all resolve to the same IP.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are doing on the side of Kubernetes is perfectly okay. A request for a certain domain, if/when received in your Ingress is correctly being routed to the backend service.

What is noteworthy is the error you show from `Chrome`. This means the address resolution problem is on your ***client*** side, not the cluster. You need to make sure that you setup local DNS resolution on your laptop so that your `www3.changed-for-privacy.com` will resolve to a `knownIPAddress`. For example, if you've set your `Ingress` externalIP to `192.168.10.10`. Then you have to add an entry to your `/etc/hosts/` file (if you're on linux) as follows:

```
www3.changed-for-privacy.com 192.168.10.10
```

This will ensure that requests for your domain from the browser land on the `Ingress` external IP (which should be routable of course) and you might find out that your cluster is working fine!

As a more permanent solution, you will of course require that your application domain is registered, so that a public DNS record for it will exist, which will map to the public `externalIP` of your `Ingress` object and you will not have this problem.

Comment: hey @zer0, thanks for the response!

just to clarify: "www3.changed-for-privacy.com" is not the actual host name i'm using, i changed it in the code snippet in my question in order to hide my actual domain. i do have a registered domain that points to the external IP of the ingress object, and it is currently working with about 9 different services (all on subdomains of the singular registered domain)
----
yes thanks for making that distinction, the issue does appear to be on the client side -- especially because it shows up with "kubectl describe ingress"

Comment: Glad it helped! Be sure to accept/upvote the answer to help others :)

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this doesn’t actually help in my situation. Sorry if that was confusing! What I meant by the issue being on the client side was that it wasn’t an issue with the ingress router being aware of the new subdomains. I miswrote — long day

Answer (score 0):

Question has been resolved!

Fortunately this had nothing to do with kubernetes! My domain is pointing to cloudflare nameservers... which I did not realize at the time. I assumed the domain was pointing to AWS nameservers. I was looking in Route 53 in AWS and was dumbfounded to see that adding a new CNAME record caused DNS name resolution errors when trying to hit the domain in the browser.

Adding the new A records in cloudflare solved my problem